# spring data and ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-data

I have funny issues with Spring Data and Oracle 12 database

I got

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   **ORA-00942**: *table or view does not*
>   exist

but it works when I use JdbcTemplate! Spring data and JdbcTemplate use the same dataSource. Liquibase migrations also work without problem

I've tried to use schema for models but no luck.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_accounts", schema = "rx")
public class CustomerAccount {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private String id;

   private String accountNo;
}

@Repository
public interface CustomerAccountRepository extends JpaRepository<CustomerAccount, String> {

}
```

But as I said it works with JdbcTemplate

```
@Repository
public class CustomerAccountDao {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public List<CustomerAccount> findAll() {
    return jdbcTemplate.query("select * from tb_accounts", (rs, i) -> {

        CustomerAccount account = new CustomerAccount();
        account.setId(rs.getString("id"));

        return account;
    });
}
```

Migration file

```
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd">

    <changeSet id="1" author="user1">
        <createTable tableName="tb_accounts">
            <column name="id" type="VARCHAR(256)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="accountNo" type="VARCHAR(256)"/>

        </createTable>

    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Any ideas? What should I check? I spent hours to find the reason but nothing helped :(

Comment: You are declaring schema in your `@Table` annotation, yet you don't specify any schema in your native query.

Comment: Native query works with and without schema. The problem with Spring Data. I've tried with and without schema but exception the same. I suppose it tells about wrong Spring Data query but why...

Comment: I guess that JDBC_Template refers to `TB_ACCOUNTS` table which exists, while Spring data tries to find `tb_accounts` table which does not exist. The table name in Oracle is case sensitive, `TB_ACCOUNTS <> tb_accounts`

Comment: year, you are right! I haven't noticed your message. Found the reason 3 mins ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to use TB_ACCOUNTS instead tb_accounts...

Comment: where does it need to use it? why?

Comment: Darn.  I have the same issue and this answer doesn't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. 1)You will use the table annotation if you already have a ready-made
   table in your database, otherwise, if there is no table in the
   database with the name you declared in the annotation, you will
   encounter the following error.
2. This error is not an error that will be big, if you give the value of spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto to none in your project and run your project 2 times, you will not get the error anymore.
3. For example, I created a project in Spring boot and created an Entity class there, and by adding @Table annotation on it, I write a table name that is not yet in my database. When I run the project you will get the error you encountered.
4. 4.If I then prevent it from recreating the table in the database in the application.properties section and run the project again, I will
   not encounter this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).